# Ubuntu 14.10 does trim SSD RAID 0 discs?

Tags: 14.10, ssd, raid, trim

I've got Ubuntu 14.10 in a RAID 0 set up with 2 x Samsung Evo 840 SSD 256Mb, for performance reasons while acessing/modificating very large files.
I've also got a schedule backup to another HDD for safety in case of raid failure.

**How do I check if Ubuntu 14.10 is TRIMING this ssd raid 0 set up?**

Comment: 14.10 should be upgraded.  There is a problem with raid and trim, and it might not get a fix. http://linux.slashdot.org/story/15/07/30/1814200/samsung-finds-fixes-bug-in-linux-trim-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find a /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim that calls /sbin/fstrim-all.

It should be calling trim on your RAID, but the way to know for sure is to call 'sh -x /sbin/fstrim-all' and see what it does.